# Unable to access the elements of a pointer to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a following array which I am passing as a pointer. BTW, I am new to C++ and just started pointers.

```
int arr[3][4]= {{2,3,4,8},{5,7,9,12},{1, 0, 6, 10}};
    //int *a = &arr[0][0];
    BuildStringFromMatrix((int *)arr, 3, 4);
```

I have a a following function with which I wanna access the elements of the passed array.

```
void BuildStringFromMatrix(int *a, int height, int width);
```

My implementation of the accessing the element is as follows

```
for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
      for(int j=0; i<width; j++){
        int x = *(*(a+i) + j);
        std::cout<<x;
      }
    }
```

While using this implementation I am getting an error

```
invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’
)
         int x = *(*(a+i) + j);
```

How can I fix this issue.

P.S - I wanna implement this using single pointer.

Comment: `i<width` --> `j<width`, `int x = *a++;`

Comment: or `int x = a[i][j]`

Comment: @bruceg `a[i]` is `int`.

Comment: `*(*(a+i) + j);` --> `a[i*width + j]`

Comment: `(int *)arr` → `*arr`

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`?

Comment: @CoolGuy unnecessary change (and arguably a bad idea due to array bounding)

Comment: @M.M `arr` decays to type `int (*)[4]`  and it is incompatible with `int*`, right? Wouldn't casting make issues because of the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @M.M apparently you solution worked for me. Thank you so much. It would be nice of you if you could tell how you get to this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function receives a pointer to `int`. It doesn't "remember" that it is actually pointing to an int that is in a 2-D array (let alone what the array dimensions are).

So if you want to access a certain element of the 2-D array you must perform a calculation to find how many units to offset from the pointer to get to the intended element.  (This is sometimes called "flattening an array").

Typically `row * row_length + column` is the offset for a particular row-column entry, so in your case `int x = a[i*width + j];` is the right statement to use.

If this is still unclear I suggest printing out the value of `i*width+j` at each iteration and seeing how it iterates over the array (or follow in your debugger).